# How to change the title registry using prefersLargeTitles?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

I know that it is possible to set font family, font size and color separately for «large» and «small» titles using `prefersLargeTitles`.

The question is: is there any options for navigation controller to show the «large title» in opened navigation panel with uppercase?

[image]

Now I use custom Navigation Controller:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    public var titleSaved: String?

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        guard let topItem = navigationBar.topItem else {
            return
        }

        if navigationBar.frame.size.height > 60 {
            topItem.title = topItem.title?.uppercased()
        } else {
            if let titleSaved = titleSaved {
                topItem.title = titleSaved
            } else {
                topItem.title = topItem.title?.applyingTransform(StringTransform(rawValue: "Title"), reverse: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Set title from View Controlle:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        let title = "Sign In"
        navigationItem.title = title

        if let nc = navigationController as? MyNavigationController {
            nc.titleSaved = title
        }
    }

}
```

this solution works, but when you switch from "large" title to "small" title and backwards it twitches and it looks pretty buggy

Comment: Do you also want to increase the height of navigation bar?

Comment: Check out this simple [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55482310/11294016).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have an uppercased title for «large title» and capitalized title for «small title» using [Small caps fonts](https://www.fontspring.com/tag/all-caps)

Change `titleTextAttributes` with other font and change `largeTitleTextAttributes` with caps font

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Sign In"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
                                                                             .font:UIFont(name: "Panton-LightCaps", size: 30)!]
    }
}
```

---

Or You can customize your font. I've created a new style font using OpenSans in http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/

You can download it [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=98882500572158795878)

```
self.title = "Sign In"
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.font:UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 30)!]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font:UIFont(name: "MyFontRegular", size: 30)!]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true 
let NavigationTitle = "Sign in"
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = NavigationTitle.uppercased()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just try to set a navigationbar title as uppercased. and set pregfersLargeTitles as true

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.title = "title".uppercased()
```

Check this:

[image]