# iOS Navbar starts as a small instead of large iOS 11 style

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

When I launch my app, my Navbar automatically starts as a small one, but I have specified in my code to use large navigation bars: `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`, I'm using a collectionView in the same ViewController.

Every time I launch my app I have to scroll down to get the iOS 11 style Navbar to appear. What could cause this problem?

Result when I launch my app:
[image: initial]

Result when I slide down and what it should look like when the app initially launches
[image: expected]

Storyboard
[image: ViewController layout]

Comment: where do you have the code [navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true] in your viewcontroller? In viewDidLoad or appear? (setting it in the story board will help too)

Comment: @NitinAlabur in viewDidLoad, but I prefer it used only on one view, setting it there will enable it for all the views that are in my navigation controller

Comment: In your storyboard, select the Navigation Bar of the Navigation Controller for the particular Tab's ViewController, and do as @HaToP has answered (select the checkbox "Prefers Large Tiles")

Comment: @NitinAlabur yes that worked, but I also found a code workaround by using `setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1), animated: true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Storyboard, select the navbar, and in the attributes selector choose the following option:

[image]